# 500 - Internal server error using ASP.net c# using charts

Tags: asp.net

iv created a web application which uses charts and gridviews, this works perfectly on my localhost. the moment i put it on my server i get the following error

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

i suspect it has something to do with the web.config file, can some one please advice me on what might be wrong

Comment: A 500 error is basically the server's "Something went boom and I can't tell you what" error. You'll have to give us more information (i.e. how about the web.config file you're suspicious of?)

Comment: If you browse the problem page on the server (i.e RDP onto the server, and fire up a browser) you should get a meaningful error message (assuming you have customErrors set to RemoteOnly in web.config)

Comment: My guess is that there is a customer handler which you need to register in the live httpHandlers config sections.

Answer (score 0):

Your referencing an image that is (obviously) unable to be found either due to the physical path you have it stored or possible permissions issues.  Ensure that you have the directory where the image is being served out of having NETWORK SERVICE read rights.